# apc enabled but symfony 3 not recognized it

Tags: xampp, symfony, apc, apcu

I installed and enabled APCu in my xampp server like:
downloaded file php_apcu.dll from (PHP 7: http://pecl.php.net/package/APCu/5.1.3/windows) and copy/paste it in the extension directory. also I enabled it from php.ini:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[...]

extension=php_apcu.dll
```

so restart both apache server and symfony server.
phpinfo() show me that apc enabled correctly:
[image]

but symfony not recognized it:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think your have successfully setup `APC` but symfony seems to somehow cache the results itself. Try following to see the updated status

> depending on os restart apache (e.g on ubuntu/debian)

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

> cd to symfony project directory and clear cache

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

And reload the page, you should see the APC will be now green(hopefully)

The actual component class that is responsible to collect these states is 
`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\ConfigDataCollector` and as I browse through its not doing anything special when rendering those red/green boxes in browser, just checking if extension is loaded and its enabled e.g the collect function does look like:

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function collect(Request $request, Response $response, \Exception $exception = null)
    {
        $this->data = array(
            'app_name' => $this->name,
            'app_version' => $this->version,
            'token' => $response->headers->get('X-Debug-Token'),
            'symfony_version' => Kernel::VERSION,
            'symfony_state' => 'unknown',
            'name' => isset($this->kernel) ? $this->kernel->getName() : 'n/a',
            'env' => isset($this->kernel) ? $this->kernel->getEnvironment() : 'n/a',
            'debug' => isset($this->kernel) ? $this->kernel->isDebug() : 'n/a',
            'php_version' => PHP_VERSION,
            'xdebug_enabled' => extension_loaded('xdebug'),
            'eaccel_enabled' => extension_loaded('eaccelerator') && ini_get('eaccelerator.enable'),
            'apc_enabled' => extension_loaded('apc') && ini_get('apc.enabled'),
            'xcache_enabled' => extension_loaded('xcache') && ini_get('xcache.cacher'),
            'wincache_enabled' => extension_loaded('wincache') && ini_get('wincache.ocenabled'),
            'zend_opcache_enabled' => extension_loaded('Zend OPcache') && ini_get('opcache.enable'),
            'bundles' => array(),
            'sapi_name' => PHP_SAPI,
        );

        if (isset($this->kernel)) {
            foreach ($this->kernel->getBundles() as $name => $bundle) {
                $this->data['bundles'][$name] = $bundle->getPath();
            }

            $this->data['symfony_state'] = $this->determineSymfonyState();
        }
    }
```

The line in question is

`'apc_enabled' => extension_loaded('apc') && ini_get('apc.enabled'),`

I had same issue and my box is green after cache:clear. But there is more to it if you want to use apc caching e.g you have to enabled specifically for some component like doctrine and validations